# Hooks necessary to create module in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want to create **registration module** in Drupal. I have created `registration.info` and wanted to create `*.module` for this. What are the **hooks** necessary to create this module?

Answer (score 0):

You need at least those hooks:

- hook_permission() if you want to limit access to URLs or pages, etc.
- hook_menu() if you want to provide some pages. For example, settings page or form.

Additional hooks:

- hook_theme() if you need to build custom HTML or override existing theming.
- hook_form(), hook_form_submit() and hook_form_validate() to build and manage forms
- hook_form_alter() to override existing forms.
- hook_menu_alter() to override existing menu items.
- other hook_*_alter() to change anything in Drupal.